# Hertzian Dipole: Why is there no longer a phase shift at $\frac\lambda2$?

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, maxwell-equations, dipole

Today we learned about the Hertzian Dipole. Out teacher told us that the length of the wire connecting the two capacitor plates is $l=\frac\lambda2$. He also stated that there is a no more phase shift (I don't know the correct English word) in the far field, which starts also at $\frac\lambda2$. Unfortunately he could not explain why the phase shift disappears in the far field and why it is at $\frac\lambda2$. I have read up on the internet and in textbooks, but only found the fact that this is the case, but not why? Are Maxwell's equations necessary to explain this? How can this be explained mathematically or physically? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: what phase shift in the far field?

Comment: electromagnetic waves are generated by the resonant circuit and these are in phase in the far field but in different phase in the near field. my question was, how does this phase change?

Comment: You should edit and rewrite your question with the information you have just given in the comment. In the sense of this amended question I do not believe that the Hertzian dipole is any different  from any *other* antenna. In fact, in all radiated, that is far, fields, the magnetic and electric components are in phase, otherwise the field would not be radiated *away*. Near fields are different, they are reactive and all antennas have that, dipole or otherwise. If this does not answer your question then you should be more specific, may be with equations what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: I could not see, why this is not a clear question. To me it is.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/788925/radio-waves-electric-and-magnetic-field-component-in-phase-away-from-the-antenna